# VB.net 2008 Invalid resx file on XP

Tags: vb.net, resources, windows-xp

Here is my problem:
I developed one application in VB.Net in VS 2008 Express Edition on MS Vista. I published the application and created the installation setup.
Now when I install this application on any Vista machine, it runs without any problems, but if I install it on an XP machine, the installation is clean, but when I launch the application, it ends abruptly without any warnings/error just after the splash screen.

Then to investigate further what I did was that I copied the source project from my VS 2008 Express Edition on Vista to an XP machine having full (VS 2008 Team System) version , and when I try to compile it there (XP/VS2008 Full), I get one error in one of the forms resx file. Incidently this is the same form that gets loaded after the splash screen.
So I see there is some correlation between my application ending just after the splash screen and failing to compile the main form of the application.
The error that I get reads like: "Invalid resx file. The parameter is incorrect Line 1374, position 5."

I am not able to understand why this is so. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.